# Android: NullPointerException in AlertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog, alert

I have the following code in my Activity

```
    View quizView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_quiz_end, null);
    TextView score = quizView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_result);
    score.setText(getString(R.string.quizzfinalResults, correctAnswers, wrongAnswers));

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_Quiz.this);
    dialog.setView(quizView)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog quizDialog = dialog.create();
    quizDialog.show();
```

Also this is the XML of the dialog_quiz_end layout
Its a simple ContraintLayout with a TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quiz_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Its pretty simple, i know. But for some reason I keep having this error. Here is the logcat.
Line 331 is "quizDialog.show()".
I wish anyone could help me.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupButtons(AlertController.java:736)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:533)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:264)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:436)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:407)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:302)
    at com.example.geotrails.UI.Activity_Quiz.endOfQuiz(Activity_Quiz.java:311)
    at com.example.geotrails.UI.Activity_Quiz.access$800(Activity_Quiz.java:39)
    at com.example.geotrails.UI.Activity_Quiz$2$1.run(Activity_Quiz.java:249)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: can you post the xml code of your  dialog_quiz_end layout ? i tested your code and it's work

Comment: @anehme done. added to the post

Comment: hmm , code is  working , try to rebuild your project ..

Comment: nop, that didn't work

Comment: use this method instead: getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_quiz_end, null, true);